# Problem with Numpy differentiating and Scipy integration in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have problem with integration an differentiation. I've tried to plot the differentitaion of x^2

```
plt.plot(0.5*(x[:-1]+x[1:]), np.diff(x**2, 1)/np.diff(x, 1))
```

And it worked. After I wanted to find the integral of x^2 times differentiation of x^2:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)     
result = spi.simps(x**2 * np.diff(x**2/np.diff(x,1)), x)
print(result)
```

But i got a ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,) (999,)

And I've also tried instead of `x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)` use `x = 0.5*(x[:-1]+x[1:])`, but no chance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` has a size of 1000 samples, the diff version only has 999 due to boundary differences.

You are actually aware of that fact when you do `0.5*(x[:-1]+x[1:])`. Same applies when you do `x**2 * np.diff(x**2/np.diff(x,1))`. Perhaps what you want to do is:

```
x_half = 0.5*(x[:-1]+x[1:])
result = spi.simps(x_half **2 * np.diff(x**2), x_half )
```

Comment: I've tried it , and it gave me the same error: **ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,) (999,)**

Comment: Oh yes, last argument should probably also be `x_half`.